# Retrieving value from nested Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm scratching my head here why I can't figure this out. It should be easy. I am trying to work with a Javascript object which looks like so:

```
Object {object: "clip", function: "list", data: Object, items: 1} (console log )
```

This Object is stored in a variable called data.
if I do     `var items = data.items` I get the number I expect (1). What I cannot seem to get is what is in the data section.

The data.data logged to the console looks like this:

```
Object {Clipid: "1", ClipprojectID: "2", Clipnote: "This is a sample clip", Clippath: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v", Clipduration: "33"…}
```

I would expect if I wanted the Clipid I would be able to do:
`var Clipid = data.data['Clipid'] or data.data.Clipid;` however this always comes up null.

I've tried a number of things, but nothing works. I'm sure it's something silly or small I'm missing but any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

If it helps the data comes from `jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString )`

**Note ** If I do this:**

```
var objd = data['data'];  
var arv = $.map(objd, function (value, key) { return value; });
```

I am able to get values like arv[0] etc but I'd prefer to go by key if possible...

**Note 2 - It's the JSON Formatting I'm decoding**

Hey sorry about this, I noticed the encoding is borked. It looks like if I do: 
console.log( data.data["\u0000Clip\u0000id"] ); it wotks! It must have to do with the json_encode.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example as jsfiddle? Your existing code looks like it should work.

Comment: Just a wild guess... try using parseJSON() instead of jQuerys jQuery.parseJSON()

Comment: Try using "JSON.parse" instead of "jQuery.parseJSON", if you see any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the JSON encode method in PHP... All the answers stated was what I had tried and are correct, it was just a valid JSON string which had had unexpected unicode characters.

To fix it I needed to do this: $json = str_replace('\u0000', "", json_encode( $response  )); Where response was my array of data to be cnverted

Answer (score 0):

There's a small typo I guess-

```
data.data.Clipid
```

note the small `i`

Comment: sorry that was a typo when writing the post, not my code. and I get undefined. It's odd.

Comment: Just a guess- `data["data"].Clipid`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data is an object, not a dictionary, so you would do `var Clipid = data.data.Clipid;` to get at the information inside.

Comment: The other way should work as well data.data['Clipid'].  Javascript Objects work kind of like dictionaries in python

Comment: Tried it I get undefined =/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do data.data['Clipid'] because you named the attributes using string literals, and the proper syntax you used (data.data.ClipId) has a typo, as mentioned.

Comment: `obj.prop1` and `obj['prop1']` are identical. The latter is bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {object: "clip", function: "list", data: {Clipid: "1", ClipprojectID: "2", Clipnote: "This is a sample clip", Clippath: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v", Clipduration: "33"}, items: 1}

console.log(object);
Object {object: "clip", function: "list", data: Object, items: 1}

console.log(object.data)
Object {Clipid: "1", ClipprojectID: "2", Clipnote: "This is a sample clip", Clippath: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v", Clipduration: "33"}

console.log(object.data.Clipid)
1
```

This works fine for me, we would need to see your code to see why you are specifically having problems.

Comment: I think it must have to do with my JSON string encoded in PHP. I;m looking at the raw source and I see its like this: '{"object":"clip","function":"list","data":{"\u0000Clip\u0000id":"1","\u0000Clip\u0000projectID":"2","\u0000Clip\u0000note":"This is a sample clip","\u0000Clip\u0000path":"http:\/\/www.jplayer.org\/video\/m4v\/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v","\u0000Clip\u0000duration":"33","\u0000Clip\u0000connection":null},"items":1}'

Comment: That makes sense, when you are printing to the console it automatically takes care of the \u0000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

if your "Object" in the "data" variable, you just have to do

```
var clipid = data.Clipid;
```